# fancybox doesnot load the content properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, fancybox

So I am appending a div to the body and this div will popup on click of on image `a` tag actually. To achieve the body overlay effect, I am using fancybox. However I am able to append the div to body, but this div doesn't load as a fancybox. Can someone help here:

My code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/xap9F/60/

Further am I missing something in the fancybox, I am also not seeing the close cross on top right corner of fancybox in chrome and clicking anywhere on fancybox just closes the fancybox, which should not be the case.

Comment: You don't seem to be able to include the fancybox CSS directly from their servers (certainly http://www.fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css gives me a 403 Forbidden.) Are you doing that in your actual code, too, or just on jsFiddle?

Comment: Also, how exactly are you trying to use Fancybox? Maybe I'm being dense, but all I see is you throwing a new DIV into your document when you click the element. I can't see anything that connects that content to Fancybox? And I can't see anything in the Fancybox documentation that suggests you can do that and have anything work...

Comment: I just need to use an overlay effect, so I gave it a shot using fancybox. Is there a better way to achieve overlay effect without using fancybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code you could use to create an overlay:

```
overlay = function () {
    var o, c;
    this.create = function (html) {
        o = $('<div />');
        c = $('<div />');
        h = $('<div>' + html + '</div>').appendTo(c);

        var o_css = {
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'background': '#000', // Background of the overlay (opacity is set later)
            'z-index': '10000',
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        };
        var c_css = {
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '50%',
            'left': '50%',
            'width': '300px', // Width of content box
            'height': '200px', // Height of the content box
            'margin-left': '-150px', // Half of content width (used to center the box)
            'margin-top': '-100px', // Half of content height (used to center the box)
            'background': '#fff', // Background of the content
            'color': '#000', // Text color
            'z-index': '10001'
        };
        var h_css = { 'padding': '10px' }; // If you want paddning

        o.css(o_css);
        c.css(c_css);
        h.css(h_css);

        o.fadeTo(0, 0).appendTo('body').fadeTo(500, 0.5); //0.5 is opacity, change from 0.1-1.0
        c.fadeTo(0, 0).appendTo('body').fadeTo(500, 1.0); //1.0 is opacity, change from 0.1-1.0
    }
    this.remove = function () {
        o.remove();
        c.remove();
    }
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    o = new overlay();
    o.create('HTML you want to fill the container with, example and image or/and text or maybe a link you later bind o.remove() to'); //This creates the overlay
    o.remove(); // .. and this removes the overlay
});
```